# Colab : Memory Allocation

Tags: memory, operating-system, google-colaboratory

I am facing the below error on google colab on one of code loops.
The Run time selected is GPU and its shows RAM as full but Disk storage usage is 35GB/ 358GB.
Can anyone suggest where I am heading wrong?

The error snippet is as below -

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 405, in _handle_workers
    pool._maintain_pool()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 246, in _maintain_pool
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 239, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 66, in _launch
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @BobSmith - I have modified my code using generator to combat the memory allocation issue in google colab.
I am facing an issue while calling a generator within a generator in python - I have posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774693/python-generator-within-another-generator
let me know your inputs.