# Python - Generator within another generator

Tags: python

I have to use the output of a generator in another generator.

Below is the code -

Here Generator 2 is called within generator 1 and the final output is received from generator 2.

I am trying to use something like below , can anyone suggest a solution ?

`def sub_gen(data) :
  for r in res_gen() :
      yield each train_datagen(r)`

## Generator 1

```
def res_gen (num_threads = 4 ):
    while (True) :
      for i in range(0,len(file_list),num_threads):
        # use multi-process to speed up
        res = []
        p = Pool(num_threads)
        patch = p.map(gen_patches,file_list[i:min(i+num_threads,len(file_list))])
        #patch = p.map(gen_patches,file_list[i:i+num_threads])
        for x in patch:
            res += x
        res1 = np.array(res)
        res1 = res1.reshape((res1.shape[0],res1.shape[1],res1.shape[2],1))
        res1 = res1.astype('float32')/255.0
        yield res1
```

## Generator 2

```
def train_datagen(res1, batch_size=4):
    indices = list(range(res1.shape[0]))
    while(True):
        np.random.shuffle(indices)    # shuffle
        for i in range(0, len(indices), batch_size):
            ge_batch_y = res1[indices[i:i+batch_size]]
            noise =  np.random.normal(0, sigma/255.0, ge_batch_y.shape)   
            #noise =  K.random_normal(ge_batch_y.shape, mean=0, stddev=sigma/255.0)
            ge_batch_x = ge_batch_y + noise  # input image = clean image + noise
            yield ge_batch_x, ge_batch_y
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you have?

Comment: I have to call the output of generator 1 within generator 2.

Comment: So you want one generator which does the jobs of both your existing generators?

Comment: Are you looking for `yield from` where you currently have `yield each` (which will be an error)?

Comment: @Blckknght - yield from would output 2 separate generator results.
I want to loop in generator 2 within generator 1 where the final outcome comes from generator 2.

Comment: @ibonyun - yes  a generator or a function (which calls a generator withing another generator ) both can solve the issue.

Comment: I think @Blckknght meant using something like `yield from train_datagen(res1)` instead of `yield res1` in the first generator.

Comment: @martineau - this is a sample of what the function is trying to achieve - yield each has not been executed - 
''' def sub_gen(data) :
  for r in res_gen() :
      yield each train_datagen(r)
'''

Comment: @Prachi: What do you expect `yield each` to do? That isn't valid Python, so it doesn't serve as a very good example for what you're trying to achieve. Does just writing `yield from` there instead of `yield each` achieve what you want? I have no idea what you mean by "2 separate generator results", since `sub_gen` would return a single stream of data.

Comment: My interpretation would make `res_gen()` yield results generated from `train_datagen(res1)` — which I think is what you want. i.e. one generator invoking the other. Perhaps you should post a [mre] to illustrate what you want to know more clearly (using numpy isn't relevant). Note that Python doesn't have an `each`.

Comment: @martineau 

 Below is what I am trying - 

1. Run generator 1. 
2. Take the output of generator 1 as input to generator 2.
3. Final results are the outputs from generator 2.
pls let me know your inputs
thanks

Comment: @Blckknght

Below is what I am trying - 
1. Run generator 1. 
2. Take the output of generator 1 as input to generator 2. 
3. Final results are the outputs from generator 2. 

let me know your inputs.

Comment: Prachi: Again that's what @Blckknght's suggestion (and my interpretation) does — i.e. what `yield from` causes to happen.

Comment: @martineau - Okay , let me run it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the only issue in your short `sub_gen` generator is that you've written `yield each` instead of `yield from`. The latter expects an iterable value after it (often another generator), and it yields each value just like an explicit for loop

So I think your code should be:

```
def sub_gen(data) :
  for r in res_gen() :
      yield from train_datagen(r)
```

Lets test this with much simpler generator functions:

```
def foo():
    yield [1, 2]
    yield [3, 4]

def bar(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        yield 10+x
        yield 20+x

def baz():
    for iterable in foo():
        yield from bar(iterable)

for value in baz():   # use the top-level generator!
    print(value)      # prints 11, 21, 12, 22, 13, 23, 14, 24 each on its own line
```